I need enable text compression to optimize my time
When I run "Lighthouse" in my angular app it show me that I have to enable a text compress . I cannot modify server configure so I follow this tutorial:
how to enable gzip compression in angular cli for production build
I Installed dependencies first and after and I put the file gulpfile.js in the same directory as package.json:
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gzip = require('gulp-gzip');

gulp.task('compress', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./dist/**/*.*'])
        .pipe(gzip())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

I modify my package.json in:
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "postbuild": "gulp compress",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
},

but when I run the
ng build --watch --base-href /Strudent/

when I run Lighthouse I show me the same problem. Can anyone help me?

You didn't describe the problem you're having.  Are you getting an error message?

If I get the drift correctly, Lighthouse complains about the compression used by your server to send the data - compressing it with gulp will do nothing, as that data is once more compressed by the server protocol to send it over the network, and it seems your server wouldn't be doing that for Lighthouse to "complain" about it.

Which server are you using that you can't configure it and it doesn't use gzip or brotli? Because production servers use compression: it saves money, and if there's one thing businesses care about, it's saving money. So if  you're using a third party hosting service you almost certainly do have a way to turn on compression, you just need to find the setting for it (or contact support).
